# Common operations on a linked list (user defined)

Tags: c++, performance, linked-list

I have just started learning data structures and for the past two days I was going through linked lists.

I have implemented the basic/common operations on the linked lists and I would love for some feedback and discuss best practices.

P.S: I will also try the STL method, but for starters I did this.

```
/*
   A list of the common operations in a linked list !
   I will keep updating it as I learn new operations
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  

struct node{
  int data  ; 
  node *next ; 
} *head ; 

class Lnklist{
   public : 
     Lnklist() ;        // initializes the head pointer to NULL at first 

     node* node_create(int) ;
     void print() ; 
     void print_with_arg(node *) ; 
     void print_recursively(node *) ; 

     // insert operations 

     void insert_at_head(int) ; 
     void insert_at_last(int) ; 
     void insert_at_pos( int , int ) ; 

     // delete operations 

     void delete_at_head() ; 
     void delete_at_last() ; 
     void delete_at_pos(int) ; 

    // reversing the linked list 

    node* reverse_iteratively(node *) ; 
    void recursively_reverse(node *) ; 
};

Lnklist::Lnklist(){
    head = NULL ;
}

node* Lnklist::node_create( int num ){

    // this allocates m/y and stores the data "num" there

    node *temp = new node() ; 
    temp->data = num ; 
    temp->next = NULL ; 
    return temp ; 
}

void Lnklist::print(){
    cout << "\nElements : " ; 
    node *temp = head ; 
    while(temp != NULL){
        cout << temp->data << " "; 
        temp = temp->next ; 
    }
    cout << endl ; 
}

void Lnklist::print_recursively(node *head){
    if (head == NULL)   {
        return ; 
    }
    cout << head->data << " " ; 
    print_recursively(head->next) ; 
}

void Lnklist::insert_at_head( int num ){

    node *temp = node_create(num) ; 

    temp->next = head ; 
    head = temp ;
    // inserted 
    print() ; 
}


void Lnklist::insert_at_last( int num ){
    node *temp = node_create(num) ; 

    // now I need to traverse till the end of the linked list !!

    node *traverse = head ; 
    while(traverse->next != NULL){
        traverse = traverse->next ; 
    }

    traverse->next = temp ; 

    // inserted at last

    print() ; 
}

void Lnklist::insert_at_pos(int pos , int num){

    node *temp = node_create(num) ; 

    cout << "\nInserting " << num << " at " << pos << "nd position " << endl; 

    node *traverse = head ;  

    for (int i = 1; i < pos-1; ++i){
        traverse = traverse->next ;
    }

    node *nth_node = traverse->next ; 
    temp->next = nth_node ; 
    traverse->next = temp ;  

    cout << "After insertion  : " ; 
    print() ; 
}

void Lnklist::delete_at_head(){
    cout << "Before deletion : " ; 

    print() ;

    node *temp = head ; 
    head = temp->next ; 
    delete temp ; 

    cout << "\nafter deletion : " ;
    print() ;
}

void Lnklist::delete_at_last(){
    cout << "\nBefore deletion : " ; 
    print() ; 

    node *traverse = head ;     

    while(traverse->next->next != NULL) {
        traverse = traverse->next ;
    }
    traverse->next = NULL ; 

    cout << "\nAfter deletion : " ; 
    print() ; 
}


void Lnklist::delete_at_pos(int pos){
    cout << "\nBefore Deletion  : " ; 
    print() ; 

    node *traverse = head; 
    for (int i = 1 ; i < pos - 1; ++i){
        traverse = traverse->next  ; 
    }

    node *to_be_deleted = traverse->next  ; 
    traverse->next = to_be_deleted->next  ; 
    delete to_be_deleted ; 

    cout << "\nAfter Deletion at position " << pos << " : " ; 
    print() ; 
}

node* Lnklist::reverse_iteratively(node *head){
    node *current, *next_node, *previous ; 
    current = head ; 
    previous = NULL ; 

    while(current != NULL){
        next_node = current->next ;
        current->next = previous ; 

        // now I need to update my variables 
        previous = current ; 
        current = next_node ; 
    }
    head = previous ; 
    return head ; 
}

void Lnklist::print_with_arg(node *temp){
    head = temp ; 
    print() ; 
}

void Lnklist::recursively_reverse(node *head){
    if (head == NULL) {
        return ; 
    }
    recursively_reverse(head->next) ; 
    cout << head->data << " " ; 
}
int main(){
    cout << "\n" ;

    Lnklist obj ; 
    obj.insert_at_head(1) ;
    obj.insert_at_head(2) ;

    cout << endl << "Inserting at last  : " << endl ; 

    obj.insert_at_last(4) ; 
    obj.insert_at_last(5) ; 

    cout << "\nInserting at a particular position : " << endl  ;

    obj.insert_at_pos(2, 10) ; 

    cout << "\nDeleting : " << "\n" 
         << "\nDeleting at the head : \n " ; 
    obj.delete_at_head() ; 

    cout << "\nDeleting at the end : \n" ; 
    obj.delete_at_last() ; 

    cout << "\nDeleting at a position : " << 2; 

    obj.delete_at_pos(2) ; 

    cout << "\nReversing the linked list recursively_reverse  : " ; 

    node *temp = obj.reverse_iteratively(head) ; 
    obj.print_with_arg(temp) ; 

    cout << "\nReversing the elements of the linked list using recursion  : " ; 
    obj.recursively_reverse(head) ; 

    cout << "\n" ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips to start with:

#### Node and global variables:

> ```
> struct node{
>  int data  ; 
>  node *next ; 
> } *head ;
> ```

A few issues with this struct: First, it declares a global pointer `*head` Notice that you have declared it at the top level scope, so the variable is a global, which defeats the purpose of a class, that is being able to have several instances of a type. If you declare another `Lnklist`, they would share this same variable. What you probably wanted was to nest this struct inside the list class. It would be a good idea placing it inside the `private` section of `Lnklist`. Second minor change would be renaming it to `Node`, to be consistent with the class naming convention:

```
class Lnklist {
public:

....

private:
    struct Node {
       int data; 
       Node* next; 
    }
    Node* head; 
};
```

#### Spacing:

This style of adding a space after every `;` is very unusual (first time I've seen it, actually). That seems pointless, and doesn't improve readability. I recommend removing that extra space after semicolons.

Some people like to put a space after the parens in function parameter lists, such as in `insert_at_last( int num )`. I personally don't see a point in that, but I wont openly advise against this one.

#### Avoid `using namespace`:

That should never be done in a header file (`.h`). For a small program like this one, it shouldn't ever be an issue, but it can cause problems in a more realistic scenario. Read a full discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

#### [Const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html):

Printing a list should not alter its contents, so those methods should be `const` to make that clear to the reader and enforce it at compile-time.

```
void print() const; 
             ^^^^^
```

The `const` must also be added to the implementation.

#### Missing a [destructor](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors):

The lack of a destructor would force a user to manually delete all nodes in the list to prevent memory leaks. If you add a class destructor to `Lnklist`, once an instance of the class goes out of scope, the destructor would automatically cleanup for you. Read the link above to know more about C++ destructors.

#### Consider using templates:

At the moment, your list is only capable of storing integer numbers. As you might know, the Standard `std::list<T>` container is a [template class](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates), which allows it to store any type the user places between the `< >` when declaring a list (e.g. a list of strings: `std::list<std::string>`). Your next exercise could be converting this list to use C++ *templates* instead of `int`s.